# Javascript function to add class to a list element based on # in url

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a javascript function to add and remove a class to a list element based on the #tag at the end of the url on a page. The page has several different states, each with a different # in the url.

I am currently using this script to change the style of a given element based on the # in the url when the user first loads the page, however if the user navigates to a different section of the page the style added on the page load stays, I would like it to change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var hash=location.hash.substring(1);

if (hash == 'strategy'){
document.getElementById('strategy_link').style.backgroundPosition ="-50px";
}
if (hash == 'branding'){
document.getElementById('branding_link').style.backgroundPosition ="-50px";
}
if (hash == 'marketing'){
document.getElementById('marketing_link').style.backgroundPosition ="-50px";
}
if (hash == 'media'){
document.getElementById('media_link').style.backgroundPosition ="-50px";
 }
if (hash == 'management'){
document.getElementById('mangement_link').style.backgroundPosition ="-50px";
}

if (hash == ''){
document.getElementById('shop1').style.display ="block";
}

</script>
```

Additionally, I am using a function to change the class of the element onClick, but when a user comes to a specific # on the page directly from another page and then clicks to a different location, two elements appear active.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function selectInList(obj)
{
    $("#circularMenu").children("li").removeClass("highlight");
    $(obj).addClass("highlight");
}
</script>
```

You can see this here:
http://www.perksconsulting.com/dev/capabilities.php#branding

.

Sorry for the lack of clarity. The question is how to modify the function listed first to add and remove the class: highlight, from the elements based on the hash in the url rather than onclick as it currently does.
I realize that I am modifying the style of the element inline with my current function, I would modify the class rather than the style.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not a single question in the above text - please form one.

Comment: Very nice site, but i didn't understand your question...

Comment: John Hartsock has the solution but, Sean, you may want to look at your code again - there is no element with id = shop1 as going to http://www.perksconsulting.com/dev/capabilities.php#doesnotexist illustrates

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your first block of javascript code.  If you set the element's style this will always override any class styles on the element. Currently, when you navigate to the page with a hash #strategy you modify the inline style of the element. I would suggest revising your code like this to modify the class of the element.

```
var hash=location.hash.substring(1); 

$('#' + hash + '_link').addClass('highlight');

if (hash == ''){ 
  $('#shop1').show()
}
```

**Edited (Regarding your comment)**

Here is what I would do:

First Create a function that adds the highlight class to a specific hash value and remove the highlight class from all others.  You would probably want a default action when an invalid hash value is passed.

```
function highlightCircularMenuIcon(hashValue) {
  if (hashValue.length) {
    $('#circularMenu li').removeClass('highlight');
    $('#' + hash + '_link').addClass('highlight');
  } else {
    //default action you did have $('#shop1').show();
  }
}
```

Second, when the document is ready (or loaded), bind the click event for each of the LI elements in the circularMenu. Then in the click function call highlightCircularMenuIcon.
Finally in the last part of the document.ready function call highlightCircularMenuIcon with the hash string from your URI.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#circularMenu li').click(function() {
    highlightCircularMenuIcon(($(this).name).replace("_link", ""));
  });

  highlightCircularMenuIcon(location.hash.substring(1)); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. Thats almost what I need. However, if you were to navigate to the page perksconsulting.com/dev/capabilities.php#branding and then click on one of the other circles on the left to view another section of the page the active ("highlight") class does not change. 

Is there a way to change it after the page is loaded using the method you have presented here?

Comment: just to let you know you have the click events hooked to the li elements but you commented them out.  I have provided in my edited answer. How I would solve this problem.  Take a look.  By the way your site looks nice. good job.